# Modify specific field in the last line of a text file

Tags: awk, sed

I'm trying to figure out whether there's a quick one liner sed or awk script that I can execute in order to modify a certain value in a text file, specifically the value in the last line of the file.

Currently my file has a trailer line with count of data lines. I want to modify this so that it includes the count including header and footer. Any help would be much appreciated.

file1 code :

```
H|ACCT|XEC|1|TEMP|20130215035845|
D|849002|48|1208004|1
D|849007|28|1208004|1
D|849007|38|1208004|1
T|3
```

After modification the output should be

```
H|ACCT|XEC|1|TEMP|20130215035845|
D|849002|48|1208004|1
D|849007|28|1208004|1
D|849007|38|1208004|1
T|5
```

Comment: are 'HDT' part of the file content, or are you just marking the lines for the sake of the question?

Comment: They are part of the file content

Comment: Could there be other line that should not be counted? That is not header, data or footer?

Comment: No, there is only one H and one T line apart from the D lines. The T line always shows the count of the D lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To modify the line that starts with T:

```
$ awk '{sub(/^T.*/,"T|"NR)}1' file
H|ACCT|XEC|1|TEMP|20130215035845|
D|849002|48|1208004|1
D|849007|28|1208004|1
D|849007|38|1208004|1
T|5
```

To modify the last line of your input file as originally requested:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s",p} {p=$0 ORS} END{sub(/\|.*/,"|"NR,p); print p}' file
H|ACCT|XEC|1|TEMP|20130215035845|
D|849002|48|1208004|1
D|849007|28|1208004|1
D|849007|38|1208004|1
T|5
```

Since there was some debate in its comments about why I downvoted a `getline` solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23622869/1745001) and since it's difficult to give examples in comments - here's a couple of examples of why you should not use that `getline` solution (or any like it) for this problem (or any like it):

Works for one set of input:

```
$ cat file1
H|ACCT|XEC|1|TEMP|20130215035845|
D|849002|48|1208004|1
D|849007|28|1208004|1
D|849007|28|1208004|1
T|3

$ awk '{printf "%s",p} {p=$0 ORS} END{sub(/\|.*/,"|"NR,p); print p}' file1
H|ACCT|XEC|1|TEMP|20130215035845|
D|849002|48|1208004|1
D|849007|28|1208004|1
D|849007|28|1208004|1
T|5

$ awk '{l=$0; if(getline==1){print l; print} else {sub("\\|.*","|"NR);print}}' file1
H|ACCT|XEC|1|TEMP|20130215035845|
D|849002|48|1208004|1
D|849007|28|1208004|1
D|849007|28|1208004|1
T|5
```

Fails for another:

```
$ cat file2
H|ACCT|XEC|1|TEMP|20130215035845|
D|849002|48|1208004|1
D|849007|28|1208004|1
T|3

$ awk '{printf "%s",p} {p=$0 ORS} END{sub(/\|.*/,"|"NR,p); print p}' file2
H|ACCT|XEC|1|TEMP|20130215035845|
D|849002|48|1208004|1
D|849007|28|1208004|1
T|4

$ awk '{l=$0; if(getline==1){print l; print} else {sub("\\|.*","|"NR);print}}' file2
H|ACCT|XEC|1|TEMP|20130215035845|
D|849002|48|1208004|1
D|849007|28|1208004|1
T|3
```

Awkward (at best) to enhance for the smallest job, e.g. printing each line to stderr for debugging:

```
$ awk '{print |"cat>&2"} {printf "%s",p} {p=$0 ORS} END{sub(/\|.*/,"|"NR,p); print p}' file2

$ awk '{print |"cat>&2"; l=$0; if(getline==1){print |"cat>&2"; print l; print} else {print |"cat>&2"; sub("\\|.*","|"NR); print}}' file1
```

Notice the difference in simplicity between modifying the 2 versions. Modifying the `getline` version is clumsy, complicated, non-trivial, non-obvious, inefficient, open to insidious errors, needing duplicated code and/or significant re-write, etc...

What we see above are the VERY common repercussions of trying to use `getline` to solve problems that awk's natural text processing mode can easily handle.

`getline` is useful when used appropriately, see http://awk.info/?tip/getline for some examples of valid applications.

Answer (score 2):

It's not strictly a one-liner, and it makes assumptions about the format of the "T" line, but:

```
(sed '${=;d;}' | sed '$s/^/T|/') < infile > outfile
```

And an awk one-liner:

```
awk '/^T/ {sub(/[0-9]*$/, NR)}; {print}' < infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2**:

- This solution *works* and is *efficient* in that it only reads the input file *once*.
- **However, for a more idiomatic `awk` solution that, too, only reads the file once, see [@Ed Morton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23636382/45375).**
- This solution uses `getline`, an `awk` function that has many pitfalls (yet also has legitimate applications) - see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline

  - Case in point: the original version of this answer was fundamentally broken in that it worked only with input files having an *odd* number of lines; see Ed's answer again for an illustration.
- Another aspect that can make `getline`-based solutions problematic in general is maintainability - modifying this solution to do more than just update the line count would be cumbersome.

---

An `awk` solution that reads the input file only *once*:

```
awk '{l=$0; while(getline==1){print l;l=$0;} sub("\\|.*","|"NR); print}' file
```

Annotated version:

```
awk '
  {
    l=$0                     # save 1st line read
    # Start a loop that reads all remaining lines.
    # Print them EXCEPT for the LAST one.
    while (getline == 1) {   # loop until the last line is read
      print l                # print the saved line now known not to be the last
      l=$0                   # save this line for the next iteration
    }
    # Getting here means: the last line was read (and is stored in $0).
    sub("\\|.*","|"NR)       # replace the part after "|" with the line count
    print                    # output modified last line
  }
  ' file
```

Note that POSIX `awk` and many implementations do not support modifying an input file *in place*, so you'll have to save the output (at least temporarily) to a different file.

However, as @Ed Morton points out, GNU `awk`, version `4.1` or higher, *does* allow in-place modification with `-i inplace` - see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace

Comment: getline doesn't necessarily return `0` if another line couldn't be read. See http://awk.info/?tip/getline. Use of getline for this is unnecessary and inappropriate anyway. Also, GNU awk DOES allow you to modify an input file in-place via `-i inplace`.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks for the pointer re `-i in place` - answer updated. Caveats re `getline` duly noted - I've also added them to the answer; however, in the _limited_ case at hand it strikes me as safe to use, allowing the file to be processed in a _single_ pass. from the Assuming the downvote is yours: unless you can demonstrate why my solution doesn't work, please undo it.

Comment: @EdMorton: As for `getline`'s return value: The manual says: `The getline command returns 1 on success, 0 on end of file, and -1 on an error.` - I've updated my explanation above to better reflect that. For brevity I decided against dealing with the `-1` case, however, as that would only occur in unusual circumstances (a file already being read suddenly no longer being readable).

Comment: I'm sorry but the use of getline for this is completely the wrong approach for the reasons listed at that FAQ so the downvote stays. The OP and others reading this question can compare the upvotes and downvotes applied to all the solutions here so if other posters disagree they can upvote this and/or downvote other solutions and I THINK this is the point of the voting at SO - so that we can all add our tuppence-worth to show how we feel about any given solution. A piece of code that produces the desired output from a given input set is just the starting point for considering a solution.

Comment: It's absolutely your prerogative to down-vote if you think the answer is not useful or actively misguided. Plus, you've _argued_ your case - kudos for that. However, I'm asking you to reconsider _this_ downvote, because I don't think your argument has merit: it can be reduced to this: "I don't like _this_ solution, because `getline` is frequently misused _in general_". In _this_ solution, `getline` is not only used _robustly_, it notably enables the _most efficient solution_ in that the input file need only be read _once_.

Comment: Both solutions I posted read the file once and neither uses `getline`. I have no problem with `getline` in general, it is a very useful command and I use it and have posted solutions using it when appropriate. I have a problem with it being used in THIS case because it is the wrong approach for THIS type of problem. **It wouldn't work if there was 1 more or 1 less line of input** and would require the OP to do a complete re-write if they want to introduce the smallest enhancement in future (try adding code to pad each line to the number of fields of line 1 or printing each line to stderr).

Comment: To make it 100% clear, I added a couple of examples to my answer of why you shouldn't use this `getline` solution for this problem. I just want to make sure anyone reading this understands why I'm being negative about this answer and that it's not simply a prejudice against `getline` in general.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks for clarifying and updating your answer. I finally get what was wrong with my original answer (just linking to the FAQ wasn't enough). I've updated my answer with a _working_ `getline` solution, but I do see your point and have added more background information and a link to your answer.

Comment: Thanks for that. You can see though that the `getline` is adding no value in the new solution, right? If you remove the `getline` loop completely and just move the `sub()` that happens when you reach the end of the file into an `END` section then you end up with the second non-getline solution in my answer. By the way - you're having to double-escape the `|` in your sub() because you're using string delimiters instead of regexp delimiters for the regexp - always use `sub(/re/,..)`, not `sub("re",..)`, unless you need to concatenate a string literal with a variable (e.g. `sub("foo" bar,..)`).

Comment: @EdMorton: Yes, I do see that your 2nd solution is a better version of mine (which is why my answer now links to it and why I up-voted it); in the end, I'd say that neither solution is particularly easy to understand, and it makes you wish `awk` had a `$` pattern for matching the last line, as `sed` does. Thanks for the pointer re regex literals in `sub()`.

Comment: That's actually a very good point - many times we want to just do something on the last line of input and we currently need to jump through hoops to make that happen (`tac file | awk 'FNR==1...' | tac` or `awk '...' file file` or `awk -v nr=$(wc -l < file) 'NR==nr...' file` or `awk '..prev=$0..; END{handle prev}' file`. A `LASTLINE` or similar construct would be very useful! I may see if I can get the gawk guys to introduce that, we just don't want awk to become another perl with a million obscure, rarely used constructs cluttering it up!

Answer (score -1):

An `awk` version

```
awk -F\| 'FNR==NR{f++;next} FNR==f {$NF=f} 1' OFS=\| file{,}
H|ACCT|XEC|1|TEMP|20130215035845|
D|849002|48|1208004|1
D|849007|28|1208004|1
D|849007|38|1208004|1
T|5
```

If `file{,}` does not work, use `file file` to read the file two times.
First time it counts the line, then update the counter to show correct lines.

---

To count only line that starts with `H` `D` and `T`

```
awk -F\| 'FNR==NR{if (/^(H|D|T)/) f++;n=NR;next} FNR==n {$NF=f} 1' OFS=\| file{,}
```

Comment: That's a short and compact code!But is it necessary to count the line all over again? Is it possible just to get the last line, then add 2 to the last field?

Comment: There are no easy way to know that you are on the last line.  You can do tings in `END` block, but then last line will be printed two times.